# How to use csvSeparator with jpexport (jprofiler)?

Tags: jprofiler

I am using jprofiler to make some tests about the memory usage of my application. I would like to include them in my build process. All the steps should work in command like.

On step exports csv file from jps file with a command like: 
~/jprofiler7/bin/jpexport q1.jps "TelemetryHeap" -format=csv q1_telemetry_heap.csv

On my local machine (widows), it is working. On my server (linux) the csv file is not well formatted:

"Time [s]","Committed size","Free size","Used size" 
0.0,30,784,000,19,558,000,11,226,000  
1.0,30,976,000,18,376,000,12,600,000  
2.0,30,976,000,16,186,000,14,790,000  
3.0,30,976,000,16,018,000,14,958,000  
4.01,30,976,000,14,576,000,16,400,000

They is no way to distinguish the comma of csv format and the one of the numbering format.

According to the documentation, I need to change the value of -Djprofiler.csvSeparator in the file bin/export.vmoptions.

But I fail. I also try to change this value in jpexport.vmoptions and in jprofiler.vmoptions.

What should I do?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in JProfiler 8.0.2.

Adding

```
-Djprofiler.csvSeparator=;
```

on a new line in bin/jpexport.vmoptions should work in JProfiler 7, though.

Comment: Thanks for answer.

OK, with jprofiler 8 (evaluation licence) I got a well formatted file.

But in the two cases (v7 and v8), I have trouble to use ';' separator instead of ','.